# How to use if else statements within Hugo along with CSS

Tags: html, css, hugo

So basically I'm creating this website for a company and I decided to use Hugo + Forestry for my stack and I've ran into a problem. I am trying to make the CSS of .pricing = none if the HUGO .md file returns the large price as false.

**My HUGO Code**

```
+++
description = "ytytyr"
large_ = false
name = "chicken"
price = 15.99
price_large = nil
small_ = true

+++
```

**My HTML Code**

```
<div class="foodItem">
<h2>{{ .name }}</h2>
<h4>{{ .description }}</h4>
<div class="p">
    <div class="pricing">
        <h4>{{ .small }}</h4>
        <h2>{{ .price }}</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="pricing lg">
        <h4>{{ .large }}</h4>
        <h2>{{ .price_large }}</h2>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Not related to your problem, but you shouldn't use headings to style your content - use classes and css instead.  Use headings for actual headings

Comment: I should mention that the HTML code is using a partial, and the original code is '        {{ range where .Site.RegularPages "Section" "dinner" }}
        {{ partial "fooditem.html" .Params }}
        {{ end }}'

Comment: The details of what you want to do are not completely clear. Do you want to hide something when `price_large` is set to false?